# Get a date and show it even after midnight for about 2 hours

Tags: php

I should be able to get the first Wednesday of each month, I can do it easily using:

```
$firstWedNextMonth = date ('d-m-Y', strtotime('first wednesday of next month'));
echo "The first wed of next month is: ".$firstWedNextMonth;
```

However, considering that the first Wednesday of next month is March 6th, the system must show this date until 3:00:00 on Thursday March 7th, at 3:00:01 instead it must indicate Wednesday, April 3rd. I do not know how to do it. Thank you

Comment: Do you know where your web server is located? PHP dates and times are based on the local time of the server. For instance, if your server is in London, all times will be GMT. You may have to calculate the difference between your current location and the server's location and execute code that way.

Comment: Maybe tell us why do you need this 3 hours margin. Is it some business rule or do you want to bypass some undesired behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I think, this should work. `+27 hours` is 24 hours + your margin (3 hours). You can test it setting `$now` to whatever you want, instead of the current time.

```
$now = time();
$firstWedThisMonth = date ('d-m-Y', strtotime('first wednesday of this month', $now));
$firstWedNextMonth = date ('d-m-Y', strtotime('first wednesday of next month', $now));
$boundaryDateTime = strtotime('+27 hours', strtotime($firstWedThisMonth));
if ($now <= $boundaryDateTime) {
    echo "The first wed of next month is: ".$firstWedThisMonth;
} else {
    echo "The first wed of next month is: ".$firstWedNextMonth;
}
```